# Search for multiple values in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have the following table in my database:

| firstName | lastName |
| --- | --- |
| Kalinda | Hemms |
| Karolyn | Greenwood |
| Aaron | Walework |
| Michel | Jurka |

Now I want to create a query with multiple strings that should return only the records with that string. For example, searching for `ka`, should return **Kalinda**, **Karolyn**, and **Michel**. This is simple and I am achieving this with

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstName LIKE '%ka%' OR lastName LIKE '%ka'
```

Now how do I create a query when my search is `ka he`? I expect to get back only **Kalinda** and **Michel**, since both values `ka` and `he` are present in their names. The biggest problem I am having is that the amount of values is unknown.

Actually I am working with JPA, but any help is welcomed.

***WHAT I TRIED***

I am making one query for each value, concatenating the results, and removing duplicates. But this brings me back **Kalinda**, **Karolyn**, and **Michel**. **Karolyn** is not supposed to be there since she does not have the value `he` in her name. Also multiple queries is not the best for the database...

***EDIT AFTER SOME ANSWERS***

After looking at some answers that helped me (hopefully) in the right direction, what I am looking for is a way to replace the `|` operator for an `AND` operator:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(firstName, lastName) SIMILAR TO '%(he|ka)%'
```

Comment: What's your database?

Comment: @stuck PostgreSQL

Comment: "I expect to get back only Karolyn and Michel" I think you meant Kalinda and not Karolyn, because `he` is not present in Karolyn's last name

Comment: Thanks @EvgeniyChekan. You are absolutely right. I changed the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution using regex and the `~` operator of PostgreSQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName)) ~ '^(?=.*he)(?=.*ka).*$'
```

For more values I just have to add `(?=.*value)` to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL, there is a great feature called [similar to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP).

Simply, you can search different keys using a regex pattern. For example:

```
select * from table where firstName similar to '%(ka|he)%'
```

In your case, you can also look `lastName` because you want to search both.

So, you may check following query and [this SQLFiddler link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2108a/2/0):

```
select * from mytable where lower(firstName) similar to '%(he|ka)%' OR lower(lastName) similar to '%(he|ka)%'
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that SIMILAR TO accepts only two alternatives, hence a query with `'%(he|ka|s)%'` will not work.

Comment: Why two? The string part is just a regular expression; it should work.

Comment: Yor're right. Was a typo in my query... But it still does not work perfectly. In your fiddle, three records are returned, but Karolyn should not be part of the result, since she don't have `he`in her name...

Comment: Oh, I see; you want both `ka` and `he` not one of them. In this case, just change the query with `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: Will also not work, because then one of the values has to be in each column. So if I am looking just for `ka` it will fail. Also keep in mind that in reality the table has more columns like department, mail, etc.

Comment: At the end, what I am looking for is a way to replace the `|` operator for an `AND` operator:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(firstName, lastName) SIMILAR TO '%(he|ka)%'`

Comment: The concat is wrong because names can be tricky. Concating them just creates new string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247835/discussion-between-stuck-and-danilo-korber).

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding correctly, you want to get everyone that has both strings somewhere in their full name.

Would this work ?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE firstName+' '+lastName LIKE '%ka%' AND firstName+' '+lastName LIKE '%he%'
```

Comment: not really, because what if the user wants to search for `ka he s` or `ka he s a`? Keep in mind that in reality the table has more columns like department, mail, etc.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't understand that it had to be dynamic depending on a space separated list. In that case can you use T-SQL for this ? You could dynamically create your SQL query by splitting the search query in T-SQL and concatenate the conditions to a query string that you would then execute.

Comment: T-SQL is valid only for Microsoft SQL. I am using PostgreSQL